# JQuery Sort ascending and descending (Not a table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with the script of sort price in MVC5

This is a View

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.Product>
@foreach (var Model in Model){
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-men">

        <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">

            <div class="men-thumb-item">
                <img src="~/Images/@Model.Product_Image" alt="" class="pro-image-front">
                <img src="~/Images/@Model.Product_Image" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
                <div class="men-cart-pro">
                    <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                        <a href="single.html" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="item-info-product">
                <h4><a href="">@Model.Product_Name</a></h4>
                <div class="info-product-price">
                    <span class="item_price price">$@Model.Product_Discount</span>
                    @if (Model.Product_Discount == Model.Product_Price)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <del>$@Model.Product_Price</del>}

                </div>
                <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details item_add single-item hvr-outline-out button2">
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Formal Blue Shirt" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30.99" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
                            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

Snippet:

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.men-pro-item').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  ascending = ascending ? false : true;

  $('.product-men').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```html
<!-- Need to add the html data before click, here -->



<!-- Button click sort -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <h6>Sort By</h6>
  <div id="filters">
    <p>
      <a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Sort by Price</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

This problem when I clicked Sort by Price, this javascript work well, but duplicate data. Because of foreach. But I cannot remove this foreach. Help me fix this code or new code if you have. Not table

> [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQzCP.png)

Comment: Can you create a working snippet with the html before the sorting, so we can see that in action?

Comment: I cannot because it's have database, before sorting this is a product page and click sort price high > low. But it's duplicate data. img below

Comment: Because you have multiple `<div class="product-men">` elements, and your `$('.product-men').html(sorted);` line of code sets the html for each one (you need an enclosing element around the `foreach` loop, and set the html for that element

Comment: @ThongHuynh you don't need a database to create an MCVE. as it's not relevant to the problem. Just copy the generated HTML and build the example from that

Comment: It's so difficult for me. I need a code about sort( not table) ..

Comment: In your internet browser, press F12 ; or right-click and choose “See source code” (or something similar). You'll have access to the html code and you will be able to copy paste it here to create a working snippet. Try not to copy all the code but all the interesting parts to make the snippet working.

Comment: Just add a  `<div id="products">` element before the `@foreach(..)` and use `$('#products').html(sorted);` (but you may need to use `var sorted = $('.product-men').sort(function (a, b) {` or just delete the `<div class="product-men">` element)

Comment: @StephenMuecke its work well, but my css fail. look at the col-3. When i click sort, the data not duplicate but this img so big

Comment: Then you need to adjust your css :)

Answer (score 2):

I played with your code and finally came to the same solution as Stephen was talking about in his comments (I saw that right after I finished).

Here is a working snippet  where I added some values to simulate it:

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.men-pro-item').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  ascending = ascending ? false : true;

  $('#products').html(sorted); // Modified

});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```css
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.item-info-product * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products"><!-- Added -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-men">
      <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <div class="item-info-product">
          <h4><a href="">Product_Name</a></h4>
          <div class="info-product-price">
            <span class="item_price price">$30.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-men">
      <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <div class="item-info-product">
          <h4><a href="">Product_Name</a></h4>
          <div class="info-product-price">
            <span class="item_price price">$25.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-men">
      <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
        <div class="item-info-product">
          <h4><a href="">Product_Name</a></h4>
          <div class="info-product-price">
            <span class="item_price price">$35.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- Added -->

<!-- Button click sort -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <h6>Sort By:</h6>
  <div id="filters">
    <p><a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Price</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.